# Script on perl for change NS records not write in file

Tags: perl

I am trying to use a perl script (I do not know perl in depth) to modify values in DNS zones.

If I print I see that it works, but I can't get it to write the result to disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DNS::ZoneParse;
use IO::File;

my $domain = @ARGV[0];

print "Value $domain";

my $zf = DNS::ZoneParse->new("/var/named/${domain}.db");
my $ns = $zf->ns();

# change ttl in NS records
$_->{ttl} = '86400' for (@$ns); #update ttl

$zf->new_serial();

print $zf->output();

# write the new zone file to disk
my $nzf = new IO::File "$zf", "w"
    or die "Error writing zonefile: $!";

print $nzf $zf->out
```

The line `print $zf->output();` write changes on screen, but other not write in file.

```
webinarinmunoferon2020.xxxxx.tld.  86400   IN      NS      ns1.wwwww.tld.
webinarinmunoferon2020.xxxxx.tld.  86400   IN      NS      ns2..wwwww.tld.
```

Comment: shouldn't this `print $nzf $zf->out` be `print $nzf $zf->output()` ? and also you should use `$nzf->close` after your print